# Why does data.table::B[A] and plyr::join(A,B) return different results?

Tags: r, data.table, plyr

I have 2 Data Tables in R

```
A <- data.table(a = 1:4, b = 12:15)
B <- data.table(a = 2:3, b = 13:14)
```

Upon using

```
C<-plyr::join(A,B)
```

it returns

```
   a  b
1: 1 12
2: 2 13
3: 3 14
4: 4 15
```

While when I use

```
setkey(A, "a")
setkey(B, "a")
B[A]
```

it returns

```
   a  b i.b
1: 1 NA  12
2: 2 13  13
3: 3 14  14
4: 4 NA  15
```

Why do we have the difference in the result for both the functions?
plyr is applying left join on all matching variables.
Data.table is doing the same right?
How can we achieve the result given by 'plyr' using 'data.table'?

Comment: Because when you don't define the `by` argument in joins, it joins all the common columns. In your case both `a` and `b`. Once you set a key, you only merge on the column of the key...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using data.table version >= 1.12.4, you can use `on=.NATURAL` (see news item 10 under section titled data.table v1.12.4 (03 Oct 2019) [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md))

```
library(data.table) #above and incl data.table_1.12.4
A <- data.table(a = 1:4, b = 12:15)
B <- data.table(a = 2:3, b = 13:14)
B[A, on=.NATURAL]
```

output:

```
   a  b
1: 1 12
2: 2 13
3: 3 14
4: 4 15
```

Answer (score 3):

*plyr* is using both (all) columns to join, *data.table* is only using the keyed `a` column.

Set the same keys, then result is the same, see:

```
setkeyv(A, c("a", "b"))
setkeyv(B, c("a", "b"))
B[A]
#    a  b
# 1: 1 12
# 2: 2 13
# 3: 3 14
# 4: 4 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another `data.table` option:

```
B[A, .(a, b = i.b)]

   a  b
1: 1 12
2: 2 13
3: 3 14
4: 4 15
```